# Changed DNS and some sections shows Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load()

Tags: nodes, debugging

I was working in the site http://www.bicevolution.com.ar/ (drupal 7) , Asked to the owner to redirect de DNS for www that were wrong. When they changed that, lot of sections of the site broke and started showing **Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load()** (like here http://www.bicevolution.com.ar/productos-para-colorear-0?id=4212 )

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, DA isn't a debugging service. The problem is specific to your environment and there's not much anyone can do besides guess at what the problem is. (FWIW, `node_load()` is a key function in the node module so you need to troubleshoot why it can't load **node.module** or the associated function within it.)